# 7z how to avoid extracting subfolders' files

Tags: 7zip, extract

I am trying to append a script in my JAVA program to unzip the files in specific folder by 7z. Here come below script. But I found that it will also extract the .zip files in subfolder.

```
7z e -aoa -ppassword c:\xxx\desktop\fromFolder -oc:\xxx\desktop\toFolder > nul:
```

What if I want to extract the .zip files located in "fromFolder" only and exclude all files in the subfolders of "fromFolder". Please advice, thanks.